# Responsive Image Columns one below anothers for desktop as well as mobile

Tags: html, css

I am writing a section in HTML template which I want responsive for desktop, mobile as well as tablet.
Code written so far is

```html
<section class="se2">
          <div class="container"></div>
          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
              <div class="row col-12">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/></div>
                <div class=" col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/></div>
                <div class=" col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
```

But this is not working on mobile.

I am getting below result for mobile screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE5fj.png)

the boxes should come one below another on mobile phone. while in same row on desktop

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: Can you specify in which `div` tag you are facing this issue?

Comment: It doesnt work after removing col-xs-offset-4 .. But this code is working fine when we run this code snippet on stackoverflow

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap v4 ? They removed the -xs infixes, so maybe you have to check the used bootstrap col classes (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="se2">
          <div class="container"></div>
          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-4">
                  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-4">
                   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-4 col-md-4">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/>
                </div>
            </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the closing div tag after the container div

```
<section class="se2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="row col-12">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.c`enter code here`om/250x250"/></div>
                <div class=" col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/></div>
                <div class=" col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```